# I fitted a Generalized Additive Model. How can I implement it in sql

Tags: model, statistics, pygam

I fitted a GAM model in python using the codes below.

```
    gam = LinearGAM(s(0, n_splines=5)).gridsearch(x[:,None],y)
and     gam.coef_ gives me this array. 
array([ 0.33231444, -0.0088823 , -0.06823895, -0.07444204, -0.10057209,
        0.08017906])
``

My question is. give this, how can I implement this gam model on new records in sql. Appreciate any insights. 

I have fitted the gam model in my data. But the package Pygam does not give specifics of the spine functions.
```

Comment: Do you mean to make prediction on  data obtained through sql ?